# Can't Validate Google Access Token (wrong number of segments)

Tags: php, google-api, jwt, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I have very simple code [directly from Google's website](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#using-a-google-api-client-library)

```
$client = new Google_Client(['client_id' => $CLIENT_ID]);

$payload = $client->verifyIdToken($id_token);

if ($payload) {
  $userid = $payload['sub'];
  echo $userid;
} else {
  // Invalid ID token
  echo "error";
}
```

I get the following error(s):

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'Wrong number of segments' in /../vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php:79
Stack trace:
#0 /../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/AccessToken/Verify.php(103): Firebase\JWT\JWT::decode('ya29.GlzbAwEXTe...', '-----BEGIN PUBL...', Array)
#1 /../vendor/google/apiclient/src/Google/Client.php(713): Google_AccessToken_Verify-&gt;verifyIdToken('ya29.GlzbAwEXTe...', '1074005180734-g...')
#2 /../pages/auth/session.php(7): Google_Client-&gt;verifyIdToken('ya29.GlzbAwEXTe...')
```

Does anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this question because the other one is too short and vague.

Instead of passing the ID returned by `profile.getId()`, pass the one returned by `googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token` as your `id_token` (the `id` field of the `POST` request you use to send the user's id over to your server).

A great tip for any developer: If you think you did everything you were supposed to do, and it is working for them, but it is not working for you, then you did not do everything you were supposed to do.

Comment: This is the Answer! Thankyou sir

Comment: This does not works. I'm with the php8.0 API

Answer (score 1):

I used access_token instead of id_token when passing it in `POST`

Comment: I had the same case.

Comment: hello, i believe answer given by @doubleOrt is the right way to do, if you dont mind accept it as correct answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and didn't get any fix. I had to change the way I was fetching user info. Instead of using `$client->verifyIdToken();` I have used the service class this way :

```
$authService=new Google_Service_Oauth2($client);
    if($client->getAccessToken()){
        $data=$authService->userinfo->get();
    }
```

So, to get the current user email, I used `$email=data['email'];`.

Hope this works!